# Calling class method from inside conditionally rendered JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Trying to call a class method from inside JSX that is stored inside a variable inside the class and conditionally rendered dependent on which step the user is on.  I am pretty sure that the issue is with my attempt using `this`.

```
class CreateGameModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            showChooseGameType: true,
            showGameLocation: false,
            showGameInfo: false,
            showSuggestedInvites: false,
            showConfirmation: false
        };

        this.onGameCreate = this.onGameCreate.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        const { hideModal } = this.props;
        const { showChooseGameType, showGameLocation, showGameInfo, showSuggestedInvites, showConfirmation } = this.state;

        return (
                <Modal style={styles.modal} isVisible={this.props.isVisible} onBackdropPress={hideModal}>
                    { showChooseGameType &&
                        this.chooseGameCard
                    }

                    { showGameLocation &&
                        this.chooseGameLocationCard
                    }

                    { showGameInfo &&
                        this.chooseGameInfoCard
                    }

                    { showSuggestedInvites &&
                        this.chooseSuggestedInvitesCard
                    }

                    { showConfirmation &&
                        this.showConfirmationCard
                    }
                </Modal>
        );
    }

    chooseGameCard = ( 
        <View style={styles.createCard}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText} numberOfLines={1} >Create Game</Text>
            <ScreenStageBar numberOfStages={4} currentStage={1}/>
            <Text style={styles.descText} numberOfLines={1}>What type of game would you like to create?</Text>
            <Button title="Next" onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ showChooseGameType: false })
                this.setState({ showGameLocation: true })
            }} />
        </View>
    );

    chooseGameLocationCard = (
        <View style={styles.createCard}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText} numberOfLines={1} >Choose Game Location!</Text>
            <ScreenStageBar numberOfStages={4} currentStage={2}/>
            <Button title="Next" onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ showGameLocation: false })
                this.setState({ showGameInfo: true })
            }} />
        </View>
    );

    chooseGameInfoCard = (
        <View style={styles.createCard}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText} numberOfLines={1}  >Enter Game Information</Text>
            <ScreenStageBar numberOfStages={4} currentStage={3}/>
            <Button title="Next" onPress={() => {
                this.setState({ showGameInfo: false })
                this.setState({ showSuggestedInvites: true })
            }} />
        </View>
    );

    showConfirmationCard = (
        <View style={styles.createCard}>
            <Text style={styles.titleText} numberOfLines={1} >Congratulations!</Text>
        </View>
    );

    chooseSuggestedInvitesCard = (
        <View style={styles.createCard}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Suggested Invites</Text>
            <ScreenStageBar numberOfStages={4} currentStage={4}/>
            <Button title="Create Game" onPress={this.onGameCreate} />
        </View>
    );

    onGameCreate = () => {
        //TODO: Add game creation logic with back end
        console.log("Press!");
        this.setState({ showSuggestedInvites: false });
        this.setState({ showConfirmation: true });
    }
}
```

The "Press" console log is not being logged and thus is not rendering the last bit of content I want to show after hitting the create game button.

Comment: It looks fine to me... Did you try logging 'this' right after 'Press'? BTW, in order to avoid `this` binding nonsense, I always prefer to use: `onPress={() => this.onGameCreate()} `, though like I say what you have looks OK.

Comment: ^ Don't think avoids `this` binding. If you want to avoid having to a method in the constructor, you can define it as an arrow function (e.g., `onGameCreate = () => { ... }`).

Comment: It does, @Nick. I use it all the time. Though the way you suggest is the other alternative.

Comment: @seesharper @Nick neither of those changes fixed the issue.  It didn't error out but also doesn't log the "Press" message from the console log now.  So it's not entering the method.  I can fix the issue by putting the ```chooseSuggestedInvitesCard``` in the render method and then calling ```chooseSuggestedInvitesCard``` rather than using ```this``` but am just curious to know why it isn't working as is.  Is it best practice to put these JSX objects in the render rather than the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Arrow function like this:

```
onGameCreate = () => {
    //TODO: Add game creation logic with back end
    console.log('Press!')
    this.setState({ showSuggestedInvites: false });
    this.setState({ showConfirmation: true });
}
```

Comment: Tried that but it did not work.  Doesn't error out now but doesn't log to ```Press``` to the console now either.

Comment: this is the correct answer.  I was calling the method incorrectly when I originally tested.